# Is there any performance difference between using > and >= in a loop

Tags: java, c, loops, conditional-statements

In loops we keep terminating conditions and we check those conditions in every pass.

I have seen 2 methods to check

1 .  `i > x`  or  `i < x`

and the second approch is

2 .  `i >= x`  or  `i <= x`

Is there any performance difference in these to 2 approaches while the logical comparison.

Is there any difference in execution time required for both operations. i.e. > and >= ?

Comment: Yes. The second one does one more iteration.

Comment: It has nothing to do with performance but with logic.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Depending on where you start..

Comment: I had heard in college that comparing with zero is more performant. So `i>=0` should be performant than `i>-1` I don't have any explanation for it though

Comment: @sidgate we generally leave it up to the compiler to determine which is best to use for the target architecture, and in the code we try to use the best logic to express the problem being solved.

Comment: @YassinHajaj that's true. Since OP is comparing them I assumed they're the same.

Comment: @sidgate In C, the generated assembly code for comparing to zero is a simple sign-check instruction (on x86 processors anyway), where comparing to other value has to actually compare. In Java, JIT may do the same, but it's unlikely to be meaningful, since you have no control over JIT.

Comment: If `x` is a variable, there is probably a performance difference between `i < x` and `i <= x-1` (which are logically equivalent unless something wraps).  The subtraction takes a bit of time.  However, if this is a loop termination condition and  `x` is a local variable, a good compiler may be able to tell that `x` cannot be changed during the loop, and do the subtraction only once.

Comment: From my experience, `i < x` is more commonly used than `i <= x` because you're usually loop over elements in an array. If you did `for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)` where x is the length of the array, you would have `i-1` scattered throughout the body of your code. If you did `for (int i = 0; i <= x -1; i++)`, you would have the same loop body but in that case, `for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)` looks a lot cleaner. If there is any performance boost from `i < x` as opposed to `i <= x`, my assumption would be that any modern compiler would optimize `i <= x`and your code to something similar to `i < x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's *very* little if any performance difference between these two statements, but there is a significant difference between the two statements and their logic flow.

For instance:

- If you have a loop that runs until `i <= 20`, you'll loop until `i == 20`.
- If you have a loop that runs until `i < 20`, you'll loop until `i == 19`.

If you have a condition that requires your iteration value to stop *before* a certain value, be sure that you pick the inequality that most suits it.

By and large, though, if there were any difference in run time or performance on this boolean statement, it would be barely noticeable.  One should not base any optimization work around switching out those statements.*

<sup>*:  Also, don't break [Rule #1 of Optimization.](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesOfOptimization)</sup>

Comment: Is there any difference in execution time required for both operations.
i.e. > and >=

Comment: For the raw boolean expression itself?  If there is, it's ***very*** insignificant, and if you're hoping to optimize your platform based on that sort of decision, there are *other* areas you should look to.

Comment: @vipinagrahari The execution time of `<` vs `<=` is the same. The execution time of iterating the loop one more time is of course directly affected by the time an iteration takes.

Comment: Isn't it frustrating when you answer a question and you get asked the same question again, as if you didn't even answer it...

Comment: @paddy I am sorry. But I actually could not understand if there is any actual difference. It will be great if you can give some reference.

Comment: @vipinagrahari:  I'd hope to clarify, but I'm not sure I can.  The difference is insignificant, if it exists at all.

Answer (score 1):

No, it makes absolutely no difference. When the compiler turns it into assembly, it turns both of them into the same `cmp` instruction.

Comment: You mean bytecode, not assembly.

Comment: No, I don't. I mean assembly. This is tagged C.

Comment: And `java`, so I guess we're both right.

Answer (score 0):

There are times you prefer to use `<=` over `<`, for instance in a `for` loop where usually we go from `0` to *length-1* (eg an array length), we use `<`. But if you want to include the compared value as well, here `y`, and keep the `<` logic, you get

```
for (x=0 ; x<y+1 ; x++) {
    ...
}
```

while doing this

```
for (x=0 ; x<=y ; x++) {
    ...
}
```

saves a `+1` calculation.

Besides that, most processors have both the *less than* and *less or equal* instructions - thus using one or the other has no impact on performance.